# Solr 4.2.1 and SOLR-1604 : ComplexPhrase AND date range queries do not work together

Tags: solr, wildcard, date-range, proximity

I recently patched my Solr 4.2.1 with the ComplexPhrase query addon (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1604). When I issue a query such as :

```
my_text_field:"testin* compl*"~1 AND my_date_field:2013-12-12T04:58:53.732Z
```

I get results that contain the text query I issued and the date I issued in the my_date_field.

But when I do this:

```
my_text_field:"testin* compl*"~1 AND my_date_field:[2013-01-01T02:58:53.732Z TO 2013-12-12T04:58:53.732Z]
```

I get no results.

If I remove the complexphrase parser things go back to normal ( but I have no support for complex phrase queries ).

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some time reading the lucene and solr code I figured it out.

This patch creates a Query Parser that extends the Lucene QueryParser. The Lucene QueryParser does not handle range queries other than Term Ranges ( simple strings in a way ). If one wants to specialize the behavior of the QueryParser, he must extract the field type and create the appropriate range query ( eg NumericRangeQuery for numbers, etc).